# Validate text box input for numeric range 1-100

Tags: arrays, vb.net, visual-studio, validation

I am trying to validate inputs to accept only a range of numbers 1-100. I have it where it will accept numbers in the range from 1-100.  What I need is how to make sure character inputs such as a letter or symbol (?,/,<,> ect...) can't be used.  I am using a loop to look through each input that is put into an array. When inputs are validated I am returning a blnOk = True to use in my button event to run program.  I have tried double.TryParse but I can't get it to work with the array. I also have Option Strict ON. dblStudentTestScores(i) is the array that the inputs are stored in.  txtTestScores(i) array is being used to tell the program which text box the loop is on so that it can gain focus with an error.

```
Private Sub ValidateScores()

    For i = 0 To 8
        If dblStudentTestScores(i) >= 0 And dblStudentTestScores(i) <= 100 Then
            blnOK = True

        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Test Score between 0 and 100")
            txtTestScores(i).Clear()
            txtTestScores(i).Focus()
            txtTestScores(i).BackColor = Color.Yellow
            blnOK = False
            Exit Sub
        End If
        txtTestScores(i).BackColor = Color.White
    Next
    blnOK = True
End Sub
```

This is the code with the IsNumeric but it won't go into the Else clause.  It jumps into the try catch. I would really like it to gain focus on the textbox that has the invalid input. Like it does if the number is not between 0 and 100.

```
 Private Sub ValidateScores()

    For i = 0 To 8
        If CInt(IsNumeric(dblStudentTestScores(i))) >= 0 And CInt(IsNumeric(dblStudentTestScores(i))) <= 100 Then
            blnOK = True

        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Test Score between 0 and 100")
            txtTestScores(i).Clear()
            txtTestScores(i).Focus()
            txtTestScores(i).BackColor = Color.Yellow
            blnOK = False
            Exit Sub
        End If
        txtTestScores(i).BackColor = Color.White
    Next
    blnOK = True
End Sub
```

Each input populates the array.

```
Public Sub PopulateTestScores()
    'Student 1 test scores
    dblStudentTestScores(0) = CDbl(txtStudent1Score1.Text)
    dblStudentTestScores(1) = CDbl(txtStudent1Score2.Text)
    dblStudentTestScores(2) = CDbl(txtStudent1Score3.Text)
    'Student 2 test scores
    dblStudentTestScores(3) = CDbl(txtStudent2Score1.Text)
    dblStudentTestScores(4) = CDbl(txtStudent2Score2.Text)
    dblStudentTestScores(5) = CDbl(txtStudent2Score3.Text)
    'Student 3 test scores
    dblStudentTestScores(6) = CDbl(txtStudent3Score1.Text)
    dblStudentTestScores(7) = CDbl(txtStudent3Score2.Text)
    dblStudentTestScores(8) = CDbl(txtStudent3Score3.Text)
End Sub
```

Comment: And what problem do you have with this code? Here is the validation tests but I can't see where you take the inputs and check if they are really numbers.

Comment: It still allows me to input characters such as ?,/,>,' and even allows a letter.  I need to only be allowed numbers to be used in the input.  The only thing I have this validation doing at this point is checking to see if the input is between 0 and 100.

Comment: You should use double.TryParse to check if the input is valid or not. Could you show the code that adds the doubles to the array?

Comment: Also, you say that you have Option Strict On so I assume that your array dblStudentTestScores is a double array. Right?

Comment: The input is a double.

Comment: I have tried the double.TryParse but I get the red line under the TryParse part of the statement.  The error says the TryParse can't accept that number of arguments.

Comment: In general, it is better to steer away from those legacy VB functions and go with the shiny new Net methods.  Double.TryParse with do the work of IsNumeric and CDbl for instance.  It would still be better if `ValidateScores` was a function returning a boolean rather than setting some global variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [double.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx) because, if the input is not a valid double, it returns false instead of throwing an exception.

```
Public Function PopulateTestScores() as Boolean
    Dim ok as Boolean
    ok = CheckInput(txtStudent1Score1.Text, 0)
    if not ok Then  
        txtStudent1Score1.Focus()
        return ok
    End if

    ok = CheckInput(txtStudent1Score2.Text, 1)
    if not ok Then  
        txtStudent1Score2.Focus()
        return ok
    End if
    .....
    return ok
End Function

private Function CheckInput(input as String, index as integer) as Boolean
    Dim d as Double        
    Dim ok as Boolean
    ok = double.TryParse(input, d)
    if ok Then dblStudentTestScores(index) = d
    return ok
End Function
```

The version of TryParse with two arguments expects the string to be in the same format of your locale (point/comma for decimals). If you want to work with different cultures then just use the appropriate TryParse overload that takes also the CultureInfo parameter.

For example, if you use the overload that takes a NumberStyles and a CultureInfo

```
ok = Double.TryParse(input, NumberStyles.None, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, d)
```

TryParse will return false if the input doesn't match your CultureInfo and the correct convention for digit grouping.

A valid double like `10.1` in en-US culture is invalid the `it-IT` one where the correct input is `10,1`

Answer (score 0):

you can check the input using the `isNumeric` function.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6cd3f6w1(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: When I use  IsNumeric it kicks out to the Try/Catch.  I need it to jump into the Else clause and give the message and focus to that text box.  The IsNumeric does stop from getting the characters and letters.  Is there a way to force it to go into the Else?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with visual basic. I am extremely rusty, but in most languages you can use a `!` to signal not, basically saying if it isn't numeric, then do this. So `if !isNumeric()`. Then just switch the code in the `else` clause to the `if` clause and vice versa